# Why do my controls get squished inside a scroll view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm building an iOS app and every time I use a scroll view and put other views and controls inside of it this happens:

[image: xCode Picture]

How do I prevent this from happening? I tried putting the scroll view in a UIView and putting a UIView inside a scroll view and putting other controls inside of the nested views but the same thing still happens. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: you need to set width constraint  or write some text  to adjust label width  behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using constraints use the autoresizing feature. The controls resize depending on the way they were placed on screen and what the settings on the Autoresizing is.

[Autoresizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTGcF.png)

Answer (score 0):

After you add something inside `scrollView`, it doesn't know what width and height it will have. Thus, it is unable to correctly display its subviews.

There are some major solutions:

1. You need to specify correct sizes AND distances both vertically and horizontally.

E.g. `scrollView` will have 1 label. Then you should specify something like this:
label 1:

`leading` = 20, `trailing` = 20, `width` = 100 (this will solve horizontal dimension)

`top` = 20, `height` = 100, `bottom` = 20 (this will solve vertical dimension)

Of course, labels are self-sizing. So if you specify the text/font/number of lines, you don't need to set fixed width and height.

2. You can add some view (if your layout allows that) which will take the whole width of the screen. In this case you set `leading` and `trailing` to 0, and instead of setting fixed width (which varies on different screen sizes), you need to center that view horizontally inside the `scrollView`.

This will solve the horizontal dimension.

Comment: I tried this and the view does follow the constraints but the contents still don't, they still get deformed. If I set a width and height constraint it does get its shape but the problem is it doesn't resize depending on the screen size. I even used >= constraints.

I managed to keep the shape and constraints and the auto resize (depending on screen size) by not using constraints. I just put the controls on the screen the way I see fit and use the Autoresizing feature instead.